# Import Drupal Database, Excluding Database Connection Parameters

Tags: database, importing-exporting

Another developer and I have the same Drupal theme installed.  The other developer is the one doing the development work and I'm simply trying to import his updates into my theme so I have the latest and greatest and can see how the work is progressing.  I am able to IMPORT his EXPORTED database, however, his MySQL database connection parameters are different in that he's not using a password, and my MySQL database connection parameter INCLUDES a password.

The way I am importing his export, is simply by using PhpMyAdmin, I first DROP all the website's Tables, and then simply IMPORT his EXPORT.

QUESTION IS: Which tables should I NOT Drop, and when he does his EXPORT, which Tables should he NOT Export... so I receive everything I need to get all the updates into my database, but don't have a problem with database connectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually never heard of database settings being stored in the database. Are you sure you aren't updating your site's **settings.php**-file as well?

Do you have different database prefixes?

Could it be related to some stale cache?

Comment: Thanks for prompting me to further probe the files.  The problem was a MySQL connection that was coded into the content page.  I needed to edit the password directly in the page, that is where the error was occurring.  We're doing some testing...

Answer (score 0):

[Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) Module could be of help to you.